# Alternatives to pointer-to-pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I find myself at a few places in my game wanting to use pointer-to-pointer in my design. For example, I have a class `OpenGLRenderer` which creates meshes given vertex/indice/texcoord data, materials given material props, etc. and then a class `ResourceManifest` which caches meshes/materials from file and upon loading one of these resources creates an instance of it using the `OpenGLRenderer`. So there is a coupling there.

I typically like to employ RAII design when coding which tempts me to the following relationship:

```
ResourceManifest(OpenGLRenderer** renderer);
```

Because when the OpenGL context has been torn down and all OpenGL state-specific stuff needs to be reinitialized, such as when recreating the window, I just recreate the `OpenGLRenderer` and let the constructor/destructor do all the work and `ResourceManifest` using it will never be the wiser.

What I am wondering is if this is enough justification of using plain old pointer-to-pointers, are there any more modern tools or techniques available? I've been looking at various smart_ptrs for example, but they do not deal with the problem at hand, as I want to recreate the managed object without passing out new smart_ptrs.

Comment: You can have a smart pointer to a smart pointer.

Comment: This could be a terrible hack, so I'm posting only as a comment; Could you reallocate the OpenGLRenderer with placement new and an explicit dtor call, thereby keeping the memory address constant? (Disclaimer: I'm a total graphics-noob)

Comment: Erm, is a reference-to-pointer too obvious an answer? Alternatively, use a wrapper type and store a reference or pointer to an instance of that wrapper, and let the wrapper's `OpenGLRenderer*` member be updated to a different renderer

Comment: To closing voters: Don't think this is opinion based, clean semantics are needed. Best alternative stated by @JonathanWakely.

Comment: There's nothing completely wrong about using the double pointer.  But you might consider encapsulating your renderer in a `RenderingEngine` class or similar - then you can just pass a reference to the the engine and let it manage the renderer.  You should avoid continually rebuilding dynamic structures in graphical applications to avoid memory fragmentation.  Alternatively, you might consider something like the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) but I think this is overthinking.  You are still approaching the problem backwards.  Consider using a scene graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already stated, you could reference a smart pointer.

However, if you also want to provide functionality beyond smart pointerness you could make your code into an iterator especially if the underlying data structures are not homogeneous.  Again, this is a matter of how you'll use your pointer to pointer.  Then whatever interface you finally use could itself be wrapped in a smart pointer.

Comment: This isn't an answer :-/ Inability to comment doesn't mean you can use answers instead.

Comment: @NikosC Fair enough, I don't want to violate rules or anything.  If I can't comment in the Answers or in the commentary is my only recourse to get 50 points?

Comment: @Cos314 I'm not going to vote on this, but I will suggest that posting comments as answers will not help you reach a reputation of 50.

Comment: @Cos314 Avoid whining. Avoid asking a counter question. Come up with an edit that shows the alternative options (best with some code samples) you want to illustrate.

Comment: Ok.  Points taken.  I didn't intend to whine and I'm sorry if it came across as such.  I was genuinely asking:  Is obtaining 50 points the only way I can add comments?  I was thinking along the lines that I might be able to add a comment that could only be posted with someone else's (higher rep) approval.

Comment: I don't think an iterator model covers the OP's concerns, he states that there's at least one (shared) `OpenGLRenderer`.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wondering is if this is enough justification of using plain old pointer-to-pointers, are there any more modern tools or techniques available? I

In your particular scenario, you could use something like that:

1. There is a class called `ResourceLoader` which contains `std::map<ResourceId, std::weak_ptr<OpenGLResource> >` where OpenGL resource is generic clas used by OpenGL resources. ResourceID is whatever you use to identify specific resource (filename, whatever)
2. When you load new resource `ResourceLoader` checks map for `weak_ptr`'s converts them to `shared_ptr` and returns them. If there are no `weak_ptr`s in map, or if they're NULL, he creates new `shared_ptr`, pushes its `weak_ptr` into map, and returns it.

   Semi-c++ peudocode (unchecked, most likely contains typos and syntax errors):

   ```
     typedef std::shared_ptr<Resource> ResourcePtr;
     typedef std::weak_ptr<Resource> ResourceWeakPtr;
     typedef std::map<ResourceId, ResourceWeakPtr> ResourceMap;

     class Loader{
     public:
          ....            
         ResourcePtr loadResource(ResourceId id){
                ResourceMap::iterator found = resoruceMap.find(id);
                ResourcePtr result;
                if ((found == resourceMap.end()) || !(result = found->second.lock())){
                     result = createResource(id);
                     resourceMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, ResourceWeakPtr(result)));
                }
                return result;                     
         }
         void reloadAllResources(){
                for (ResourceMap::iterator i = resourceMap.begin(); i != resourceMap.end(); i++){
                     ResourcePtr cur = i->second.lock();
                     if (cur)
                          cur->reload();
                }
         }
     protected:
         ResourceMap resourceMap;
         ResourcePtr createResource(ResourceId id){
               return ResourcePtr(new Resource());
         }
     };
   ```
3. When you want to realod lost resources, you simply iterate through resourceMap, and call reload on every object that hasn't expired. See `reloadAllResources`

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure I fully understand your question, but let me give it a shot: could you use [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)?

Consider the following (contrived) example:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

class Renderer {
 public:
  Renderer()
      : m_calls(0) { }
  void render() {
    m_calls++;
    std::cout<<"Issued render call #"<<m_calls<<std::endl;
  }
  void reset() {
    std::cout<<"Reset called"<<std::endl;
    m_calls = 0;
  }
 private:
  size_t m_calls;  
};

class Context {
 public:
  Context(std::shared_ptr<Renderer> prenderer)
      : m_prenderer(prenderer) {
  }
  void build_cache() {
    if(auto renderer = m_prenderer.lock()) {
      renderer->render();
    } else {
      std::cout<<"Handle the case when I don't have a renderer to work with"<<std::endl;
    }
  }  
 private:
  std::weak_ptr<Renderer> m_prenderer;  
};


int main() {
  auto renderer = std::make_shared<Renderer>();
  Context ctx(renderer);
  ctx.build_cache();
  ctx.build_cache();
  std::cout<<"Here I reset the renderer"<<std::endl;
  renderer->reset();
  ctx.build_cache();

}
```

Compiled as: `g++ example.cpp -std=c++11` (gcc 4.7.2). Output:

```
Issued render call #1
Issued render call #2
Here I reset the renderer
Reset called
Issued render call #1
```

The purpose of `std::weak_ptr` is to share a pointer without sharing ownership. So you could reset or completely recreate your `Renderer`, and it would be immaterial to `Context`. Also, dereferencing to a null pointer has well-defined behavior.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem.  If a new `Renderer` is created how do you update `Context::m_prenderer`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely you are right - I don't have an answer to this question (I tried to reset the shared pointer, and hope that the weak pointer would dereference to the new shared pointer, it obviously did not work). In other words... by tweaking it, I'm converging to the case "pointer to a pointer", which leaves me in the original situation. Oh well!